# What format are Animoji messages once copied out of Messages.app?

Tags: ios, animoji

I assume they are a video file but does someone have a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are indeed a video file, of resolution 640×480, at 60 fps.

https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/908342119269625856